# How to Update Two Tables using LINQ in ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I'm making Library Management System project in which I have a `Deposit` Controller which deposits the earlier issued books. Two tables are used:

1. BooksData
2. BookDepositIssue

`BooksData` has all book info with a `BookStatus` Flag which sets 'A' for Available and 'I' for Issued.
`BookDepositIssue` has `BookID` which is common in both tables and `IssueDate, DepositDate, and DueDate`.

Now in my deposit controller I'm checking if the `BookStatus` flag is "I"; which means Issued. And also `DueDate<= DateTime`.Today so that no fine is incurred. But I'm unable to make the correct code pls help. As shown by the debugger var v is getting null, thus not going into the if condition. The database has issued books whose flag is "I" then why it is not executing the condition?

**Controller part**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Deposit (BookDepositIssue deposit)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        using (LibraryEntities dc = new LibraryEntities())
        {
            var v = dc.BooksDatas.Where(a=> a.BookStatus.Equals("I") && a.BookID.Equals(deposit.BookID) && deposit.DueDate<=DateTime.Today).FirstOrDefault();
            if(v!=null)
             {
                v.BookStatus="A";
                deposit.depositDate = DateTime.Today;
             }
            UpdateModel(dc.BooksDatas);
            UpdateModel(dc.BookDepositIssues);
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }
      }
    }
```

**Model Part**

```
      Model class 1:
      public partial class BookDepositIssue
      {
      public int SequenceNo {get; set;}
      public string BookID {get; set;}
      public string ID {get; set;}
      public Nullable<System.DateTime> IssueDate {get; set;}
      public Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate {get; set;}
      public Nullable<System.DateTime> DepositDate {get; set;}
      }

     Model Class 2:
     public partial class BooksData
     {
     public string BookID {get; set;}
     public BookName {get; set;}
     public BookGenre {get; set;}
     public BookStatus {get; set;}
     public Author {get; set;}
     }
```

Comment: can you explain what exactly isn't working? is `v` always null? or the changes you make not being saved?

Comment: btw, I hope I'm getting this correctly, but why use the lambda expression? you have the deposit object. why not use a navigation property from BookDepositIssue to BooksData? you don't need this `a=> a.BookStatus.Equals("I") && a.BookID.Equals(deposit.BookID)`

Comment: can you please make the code?

Comment: I need to understand what's wrong first, is `v` always null? or is the data not being saved?

Comment: v will be null only if the flag against a BookID is 'A' which means the book is available. The deposit of a book should only work if the flag is 'I' for a BookID, which means the book is issued.

Comment: ya I understand the logic, I still don't understand which part of your code is not working, what errors are you getting? or what part needs to be fixed.

Comment: you need to be more specific when you ask this question, for example you should say I get the right object but it's not being saved to the db, or v is always returning null instead of correct value...

Comment: there is no error but I'm trying to deposit the book which was being issued; of which the flag is currently 'I' in the database. So when the database has a BookID of which the BookStatus Flag is 'I' then why it is not fetching that row? Why it is bouncing off the IF (v !=null) condition?

Comment: I have mentioned var v is getting null in my last line of description. Do you  have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

try this - assuming you have a navigation property between `BookDepositIssue` to 'BookDepositIssue' named `bookData`. if you don't have one, you should.

replace this part:

```
var v = dc.BooksDatas.Where(a=> a.BookStatus.Equals("I") && a.BookID.Equals(deposit.BookID) && deposit.DueDate<=DateTime.Today).FirstOrDefault();
            if(v!=null)
             {
                v.BookStatus="A";
                deposit.depositDate = DateTime.Today;
             }
            UpdateModel(dc.BooksDatas);
            UpdateModel(dc.BookDepositIssues);
            dc.SaveChanges();
```

with this:

```
if(deposit.bookData.BookStatus == "I" && deposit.DueDate<=DateTime.Today){
    deposit.bookData.BookStatus = "A";
    deposit.depositDate = DateTime.Today;
}
dc.SaveChanges();
```

let me know if that worked for you. if not please be specific on what is not working.

Comment: Still not working. First of all deposit is the object of 'BookDepositIssue'  table, not BooksData table. And when I try to type : if (BooksData.BookStatus....)  the auto-complete doesn't show 'BookStatus'. It is showing Equals and ReferenceEquals after the dot.
I have used ADO.NET Entity Data Model to populate my Database.edmx, Is there anything to do with it?

Comment: can you please update your questions and add the model classes? cause you said `BooksData has all book info with a BookStatus Flag which sets 'A' for Available and 'I' for Issued.`

Comment: btw this won't work `if (BooksData.BookStatus....)` this is a static call, you can't make a static call to object instance values...
you need to run this on the BooksData object instance not the class name

Comment: I'm assuming you used model first approach here? I would advice to add a navigation property to class `BookDepositIssue` to get easy access to the `BooksData` object.

Comment: With ADO.NET entity model, Model classes are created automatically. And I'm just inheriting them in my Views. What is the navigation property?

Comment: wait.. in your model I now see that `BookGenre` is not a string as I thought it is, is it a enum?

Comment: read this for navigation property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

and I also need to know what is BookGenre type.

Comment: All the columns are of nvarchar type even the BookStatus is nvarchar not nchar.